# Find the inverse of $x^3+x$ mod $x^4+x+1$ in $F_2[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I did a huge amount of algebra and I think I ended up with the wrong answer. I got $(-x^4+3x^3-x^2-2x)$ which is obviously not the right answer.

So I started by saying I need $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ such that 
$a(x^4+x+1) + b(x^3 +x)=1$ and $b(x)$ will be the inverse. Then I tried to use the extended Euclidiean algorithm which took forever. I got:

$$x^4+x+1 = (x^3+x)(x) + (-x^2+x+1)$$

$$x^3+x = (-x^2+x+1)(-x-1) + (3x+1)$$

Then since $3x \equiv x \pmod 2$,

$$(-x^2+x+1) = (x+1)(-x+2) + (-1)$$

Since -1 = 1, I stopped there and got the gcd as 1. However when I did the extended version it did not seem to work. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 5):

The Euclidean Algorithm can be done using matrices:

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&0&x^4 + x + 1\\0&1&x^3+x\end{array}\right]$$
Now take row 1 and add/subtract $x$ times row 2 from it:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&x&x^2 + x + 1\\0&1&x^3+x\end{array}\right]$$
Now take row 2 and add/subtract $x+1$ times row 1 from it:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}1&x&x^2 + x + 1\\x+1&x^2+x+1&x+1\end{array}\right]$$
Now take row 1 and add/subtract $x$ times row 2 from it:
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}x^2+x+1&x^3+x^2&1\\x+1&x^2+x+1&x+1\end{array}\right]$$
Now read off row 1 as an equation, giving the Bezout coefficients:
$$(x^2+x+1)(x^4+x+1)+(x^3+x^2)(x^3+x)=1,$$
which implies that $(x^3+x)^{-1}\equiv(x^3+x^2)\pmod{x^4+x+1}$.

(Note that this also works for the gcd of two or more *numbers*; just make sure you're subtracting an *integer* times a row.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Normally when we solve something with a matrix you get the identity on the right side. So when do you know where to stop with these matries ?

Comment: Normally you stop when only one entry in the right-most column is zero. You can stop when one of the entries is 1, though.